# Roots of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I was studying for my maths quiz and I had some questions to ask about the answer

The answer is provided here:
[image: Answer]

Here comes my question. 
1. How did [sqrt2/2 e^j3pi/4)]^-2/3 became [1/2 e^j3pi/4]^1/3?

2. How did (2e^j-3pi/4)^1/3 become (2e^jpi/2)^1/3?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think that 3pi/4 should become a 3pi/2 once that -2/3 becomes a -1/3

Comment: A friendly note, by visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you can learn how to type mathematics on this site to make your equations easier to read.

Comment: @JMoravitz. I know how I could have done it properly, honestly, I was lazy and called to task when typing the suggestion...:)

Comment: @imranfat I wasn't referring to your comment, I was referring to the OP's use of `[1/2 e^j3pi/4]^1/3`.  Yours on the other hand is perfectly readable and I probably wouldn't have texed it either.

Comment: @imranfat how did -2/3 become -1/3 u have any idea? I was thinking it maybe because of x2

Comment: @QingYong it looks like he did $(\dots)^{-\frac{2}{3}} = ((\dots)^{2})^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ and distributed the two onto the exponents.  $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2=\frac{1}{2}$, but it appears that the posted solutions have an error as mentioned half an hour ago by imranfat that it should have had the exponent on the $e$ also change by a factor of two to $3^{\frac{j3\pi}{2}}$ instead of as written as $3^{\frac{j3\pi}{4}}$.  It appears that the mistake was magically corrected two lines later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was to evaluate $(-\frac{1}{2}+j\frac{1}{2})^{-\frac{2}{3}}$  (where $j$ is the imaginary unit).

The solution key is correct up to a time but has an error where you see the whiteout as well as an error which somehow corrected his earlier error two lines later.  The locations of the errors are marked in red below but have been fixed in my post.  It was likely just a transcription error on the person's part who wrote up the solution.

$$\begin{array}{rll}
(-\frac{1}{2}+j\frac{1}{2})^{-\frac{2}{3}}&=[\frac{1}{2}(-1+j)]^{-\frac{2}{3}} & \text{factor out common} \frac{1}{2}\\
&=[\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}e^{j\frac{3\pi}{4}})]^{-\frac{2}{3}}&\text{rewriting parenthesis as polar form}\\
&=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}e^{j\frac{3\pi}{4}})^{-\frac{2}{3}}&\text{distribute the}~\frac{1}{2}\\
&=(\frac{1}{2}e^{j\frac{3\pi}{\color{red}{2}}})^{-\frac{1}{3}}&\text{distribute exponent of $2$ inside the parenthesis}\\
&=(2e^{-j\frac{3\pi}{2}})^{\frac{1}{3}}&\text{distribute exponent of $-1$ inside the parenthesis}\\
&=(2e^{j\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}})^{\frac{1}{3}}&\text{by the fact}~-\frac{3\pi}{2}~\text{and}~\frac{\pi}{2}~ \text{are equivalent angles}\\
&=2^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{j\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}{3}}~\text{for}~k=0,1,2&\text{By DeMoivre's}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Anyway how did the distribute exponent of 2 lead to (12ej3π2)−1/3? Could u further explain thanks

Comment: \begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2e^{\;\large j\frac{3\pi}4}\right)^{\large-\frac23}&=\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2e^{\;\large j\frac{3\pi}4}\right)^2\right)^{\large-\frac13}\\
&=\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)^2\left(e^{\;\large j\frac{3\pi}4}\right)^2\right)^{\large-\frac13}\\
&=\left(\left(\frac24\right)\left(e^{\;\large j\frac{3\pi}4\times2}\right)\right)^{\large-\frac13}\\
&=\left(\frac12e^{\;\large j\frac{3\pi}2}\right)^{\large-\frac13}
\end{align}

Comment: To get the second line, I used the fact that $(ab)^2=(a)^2(b)^2$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus thanks. But how did the power changed from -2/3 to -1/3?

Comment: @QingYong we are using properties of exponentiation.  You have that $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$.  Using that property with $a$ as what is inside the parenthesis, $b$ as $2$ and $c$ as $-\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the clarification and answer :D